# First steps to internatinalize the language in Plone 2.5

Tags: internationalization, plone, linguaplone

I trying to use `i18n` in my `Plone 2.5` project but didn't found anything that can help me.

Anyone already found something teaching how to do it?

Comment: Have you considered upgrading your Plone? ... please!

Comment: What is "i18n" for you? Contents internationalization? User interface internationalization?
Please be more specific... and yes: *please* upgrade your Plone!

Comment: @Danimal  I can't update because I started to work with Plone, also learning. I will suggest this for the person but I don't know if this can happen

Answer (score 1):

You will have a hard time finding the information nowadays. Recent developer docs target Plone 4.x versions. Nevertheless it is possible do to that today. But you will build up deprecated knowledge. Plone 2.5 used the Placeless Translation Service for providing code-level and content-level translation. It helps to differentiate between these two when asking questions.

Best approach: Grab the free Plone Book from Andy McKay "Plone - the definite guide" targetting Plone 2.5 - released in year 2005. It may have a chapter about i18n/l10n. Years ago it was available to the public. This book shows how you do things the Plone 2.5 way.

Refs

- [Definite Guide to Plone (PDF)](https://plone.org/documentation/kb-old/definitive-guide/definitive_guide_to_plone.pdf)
- [Internationalization (i18n) today using Plone 4.3](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/i18n/internationalisation.html#placelesstranslationservice)

Comment: Just a note: "Definite guide to Plone" first edition was targeted Plone 2.0, still it can be a good starting point

Comment: @keul I started to read also `Building Websites with Plone` and there has something about `i18n` but I can't do because the files changed. I know something about this in `Plone 4` but need to learn in the early versions.